# How to send information Google Checkout through an API?

Tags: google-checkout

Has any one integrated Google Checkout?  I have already tried with example provided on Google Checkout help and it working fine but I want to send credit card information and other informations like address, name, etc from my web site through an API. I am not finding any way to do this.

Comment: When you say you want to send credit card information, do you also mean you want to store it? The credit card companies are really strict about this sort of thing - you need to be PCI-compliant to avoid getting into trouble, and getting certification is a process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some information on the Google Checkout SDK.

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Google Checkout lets you send name and address but not the credit card information.
This way customer billing information is protected.

To collect credit card numbers on your website and send them to a payment processor, you need to get a merchant account or just use [Paypal Pro](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-vt-fees-outside) (I think its $30/month).

Comment: I would avoid gathering credit card information on my site at all. The security and legal issues around that are WAY more than it's worth for 99% of sites. Let a 3rd party deal with that overhead.